# Writing bytes to a file using library f.el

Tags: files, functions, apply

I'm trying to do something very simple, write bytes to a file using the f library:

`(require 'f)`

And I create a list of bytes:

`(setq random-data (loop for i from 0 to 40 collect (random 150)))`

So far, so good.  However, the `unibyte-string` function seemingly expects separate arguments so the following doesn't work:

`(f-write-bytes (unibyte-string random-data) "file.dat")`

This seems painfully easy but I can't get it working, is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `apply` the function to the list of arguments:

```
(f-write-bytes (apply 'unibyte-string random-data) "file.dat")
```

`(apply '+ '(1 2 3))` is equivalent to `(+ 1 2 3)`. See the [section about calling functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) in the elisp manual for more details.

Comment: Many thanks - I thought there'd be a lispy way of doing it!

Comment: Yeah, though I had to jog my memory too, my first instinct was "Wasn't there an unpacking operator like Python's `*`?" ;)